# bash regex to find and save string from file

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

My file, `hi.html`, has many lines of text. I need to hunt down the line that starts with

```
Hello abc123 blah blah blah
```

and then save to `myvariable` whatever text is in the position of `abc123` which will change from time to time, but `Hello` is hard coded and will always be 'Hello'. Note that a space delimits both sides of the text occupied by the all important `abc123`.

Answer (score 9):

First, an obligatory warning. It is usually [a very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1081936) to try to parse HTML with simple tools like regular expressions. That said, in this case, if you are sure that what you want will always be the second word on a line that starts with `Hello`, you can use one of:

1. GNU `grep`

   ```
   grep -oP '^Hello\s+\K\S+'
   ```

   This is `grep` with Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (`-P`) and `-o` to tell it to only print the matched portion of the line. The regex itself looks for `Hello`, then one or more whitespace characters (`\s+`) and then discards it (`\K`) and then 1 or more non-whitespace characters (`\S+`).
2. awk

   ```
   awk '$1=="Hello"{print $2}' file
   ```

   `awk` will automatically split its input lines on whitespace and the 1st field will be `$1`, the second `$2` etc. Therefore, this script will print the second field if the first one is `Hello`. Note that it won't match `Helooo`. If you want all lines whose first *characters* are `Hello` and not necessarily only those whose first word is exactly `Hello`, use this instead:

   ```
   awk '/^Hello/{print $2}' file
   ```

With both approaches, to save the output in a variable, use [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

```
myvariable=$(grep -oP '^Hello\s+\K\S+')
myvariable=$(awk '/^Hello/{print $2}' file)
```

Answer (score 4):

If your `grep` supports PCRE, you can do:

```
grep -Po '^Hello \K[^ ]+(?= )' hi.html
```

To save it in a variable:

```
myvariable="$(grep -Po '^Hello \K[^ ]+(?= )' hi.html)"
```

Alternate `sed` way:

```
sed -n 's/^Hello \([^ ]\+\) .*/\1/p' hi.html
```

To save it in `myvariable`:

```
myvariable="$(sed -n 's/^Hello \([^ ]\+\) .*/\1/p' hi.html)"
```

Note that parsing html using Regex might not be a good idea.